# Why does US-ASCII encoding accept non US-ASCII characters?

Tags: java, encoding, utf-8, ascii, non-ascii-characters

Consider the following code:

```
public class ReadingTest {

    public void readAndPrint(String usingEncoding) throws Exception {
        ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(new byte[]{(byte) 0xC2, (byte) 0xB5}); // 'micro' sign UTF-8 representation
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(bais, usingEncoding);
        char[] cbuf = new char[2];
        isr.read(cbuf);
        System.out.println(cbuf[0]+" "+(int) cbuf[0]);
    }

    public static void main(String[] argv) throws Exception {
        ReadingTest w = new ReadingTest();
        w.readAndPrint("UTF-8");
        w.readAndPrint("US-ASCII");
    }
}
```

Observed output:

```
µ 181
? 65533
```

Why does the second call of `readAndPrint()` (the one using US-ASCII) succeed? I would expect it to throw an error, since the input is not a proper character in this encoding. What is the place in the Java API or JLS which mandates this behavior?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The default operation when finding un-decodable bytes in the input-stream is to replace them with the Unicode Character [U+FFFD REPLACEMENT CHARACTER](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/fffd/index.htm).

If you want to change that, you can pass a [`CharacterDecoder`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/charset/CharsetDecoder.html) [to the `InputStreamReader`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/InputStreamReader.html#InputStreamReader(java.io.InputStream,%20java.nio.charset.CharsetDecoder)) which has a different [`CodingErrorAction`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/charset/CodingErrorAction.html) configured:

```
CharsetDecoder decoder = Charset.forName(usingEncoding).newDecoder();
decoder.onMalformedInput(CodingErrorAction.REPORT);
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(bais, decoder);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The problem is I can't easily change the code which creates the `InputStreamReader`, because it's not mine - `org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.SQLExec.Transaction.runTransaction(PrintStream)`. I was surprised to learn the `encoding` attribute of Ant's `<sql>` task doesn't prevent malformed input.

Comment: @Grzegorz: I'd consider that a bug. At least when `encoding` is specified, the task should enforce the encoding, including reporting errors. If it's unspecified, then it's probably better to be error-tolerant. Maybe adding a `strictEncoding` attribute or something like that would be appropriate.

Comment: I've filed an issue in Ant's bug database: https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=50715 but I don't hope for the issue to be resolved soon.

Answer (score 3):

I'd say, this is the same as for the constructor
`String(byte bytes[], int offset, int length, Charset charset)`:

> This method always replaces malformed-input and unmappable-character sequences with this charset's default replacement string. The java.nio.charset.CharsetDecoder class should be used when more control over the decoding process is required.

Using `CharsetDecoder` you can specify a different `CodingErrorAction`.